# Stored procedure to get all the resultor data based on parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure where if I give parameters then it should query base on that else it should give me all the results

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc1] 
    @ID varchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    set @sql = 'SELECT * from Table1
                WHERE (ID IN (' + @ID + '))'

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    begin
       exec(@sql)
    end
END
```

When I pass 2 parameters, it works. When I pass 1 parameter it works.

But I want that when I do not pass any parameter, it should result me all the data.

So, I tried:

```
 (ID IN ('+@ID+') or ('+@ID+')='''')
```

But it does not work.

Can anyone please suggest how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When i write my stored procedures i set the value to a default that triggers that logic. So if no parameters are sent into the stored procedure the value will default and trigger the logic, else it will use the ID value.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc1] 
    @ID varchar(max) = NULL -- Set the default here
AS
BEGIN

IF @ID IS NULL BEGIN 

-- Do the @ID value is not set logic here

END 
ELSE BEGIN 

-- Do the @ID value is set logic here 

END
```

This is an explanation from Microsoft of what i did right there [IF...ELSE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)